# How to find which parameter has choice alternatives

Tags: python, suds

Using latest version of suds (or its live fork, suds-jurko), suds can parse choice parameters and doesn't need to be patched ([#342](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/342)). But, the question is how one can figure out from suds (programmatically) which parameter has choice alternatives and how those can be selected when a method is called.